# How to enable CORS in MEAN STACK web app?

Tags: angularjs, node.js, mean-stack

I am working on a MEAN-STACK application.Using Mean-cli packgae of node.
in which i am using darksky weather API,
in package name Information. I have 4 other packages in custom folder of mean app.
how did i enable the CORS so that all API request did not fail and return the response.

i googled and find out that i have to add this middleware.

```
 //CORS middleware
var allowCrossDomain = function(req, res, next) {
    res.header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', 'example.com');
    res.header('Access-Control-Allow-Methods', 'GET,PUT,POST,DELETE');
    res.header('Access-Control-Allow-Headers', 'Content-Type');
    next();
}
```

where should i add this. in each package where we are using cross-origin request or in some global file.

I have tried to add this middleware in server -route file of ? Information package and in express.js file of confile but it didn't work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So the actual solution to your issue turned out to be using `jsonp` callback with forecast.io api as they haven't enabled CORS headers for client access. Use `$http.jsonp` like this

```
$http.jsonp(url + lat + ',' + lng + '?callback=JSON_CALLBACK');
```

In general to enable CORS on your expressjs server do the following.

1. Install [cors](https://www.npmjs.com/package/cors) module for express with `npm install cors`
2. require it `var cors = require('cors');`
3. Set it on your express app instance with `app.use(cors());`

`cors` module will automatically add all aors related headers on the response. Alternately you could also configure a lot of options. Check the [official docs](https://github.com/troygoode/node-cors)

OR

If you want to do it yourself you could do the following

```
var permitCrossDomainRequests = function(req, res, next) {
res.header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', '*');
res.header('Access-Control-Allow-Methods', 'GET,PUT,POST,DELETE');
res.header('Access-Control-Allow-Headers', 'Content-Type');
// some browsers send a pre-flight OPTIONS request to check if CORS is enabled so you have to also respond to that
if ('OPTIONS' === req.method) {
  res.send(200);
}
else {
  next();
}
};
```

then Enable your CORS middleware

```
app.use(permitCrossDomainRequests);
```

Enable routes at the end

```
app.use(app.router);
```

Comment: tried this but not working neither in local nor in aws

Comment: @ashish_pbh what errors are you getting on is console or in network tab of chrome dev tools?

Comment: The error is for accessing forecast io issue , not your own server. Your enabling cors on your server is not going to fix your issue

Comment: Use jsonp to call forecast.io apis from your client-side angular javascript. Hint: use `$http.jsonp` like this `$http.jsonp(url + lat + ',' + lng + '?callback=JSON_CALLBACK');`

Answer (score 1):

If you only have one Express server, you only need to add the middleware once. Your other modules are probably provided as middleware to the server.

If you register a middleware function without any qualifying path, like `app.use(function(){ ... })`, the middleware will run for every request processed by the server. It does not matter what other middleware is invoked by any given request.

If you have multiple Express servers running simultaneously (this is fairly unlikely), then you will need to add the middleware to each server.