# Fetch: post json data, application/json change to text/plain

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, ecmascript-6

I'm using chrome 53.0.2785.116 m (64-bit).

I got the following headers on devtools. The problem is marked with a "//" comment. content type is really not allowing us to set it to application/json, I have tried a 100 different ways.

```
import fetch from 'isomorphic-fetch';
const option = {
    method: 'POST',
    mode: 'no-cors',
    headers: {
      'Accept': 'application/json',
      'Content-Type': 'application/json'
    },
    body: JSON.stringify({'aa':'bb'})
}
fetch('/books', opts)
.then(check401)
.then(check404)
.then(jsonParse)
.then(errorMessageParse);
```

Request Headers

```
accept:application/json
Accept-Encoding:gzip, deflate
Accept-Language:zh-CN,zh;q=0.8
Connection:keep-alive
Content-Length:97
content-type:text/plain;charset=UTF-8 //What happen?
Host:127.0.0.1:8989
Origin:http://127.0.0.1:8989
Referer:http://127.0.0.1:8989/
User-Agent:Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/53.0.2785.116 Safari/537.36
```

Comment: Note, an object `option` is created, though  `opts` is passed to `fetch`.

Answer (score 37, accepted):

The problem is that when you work in 'mode' 'no-cors', the Headers become an immutable and you will not be able to change some of its entries. One of the heads you can't change is the Content-Type. When you set 'mode' to 'no-cors' you will be able to change only these headers:

- `Accept`
- `Accept-Language`
- `Content-Language`
- `Content-Type` and whose value, once parsed, has a MIME type (ignoring parameters) that is `application/x-www-form-urlencoded`, `multipart/form-data`, or `text/plain`

In another words, in 'mode' '-no-'cors' you can only set `application/x-www-form-urlencoded`, `multipart/form-data`, or `text/plain` to the `Content-Type`.

So the solution is stop using fetch or changing it to 'cors' 'mode'. Of course this will only works if your server also accepts 'cors' requests.

Here is an example of how you could enable CORS in an Apache Server

```
SetEnvIfNoCase Access-Control-Request-Method "(GET|POST|PUT|DELETE|OPTIONS)" IsPreflight=1
SetEnvIfNoCase Origin ".*" AccessControlAllowOrigin=$0
SetEnvIfNoCase Origin "https://(url1.com|url2.com)$" AccessControlAllowOrigin=$0

Header always set Access-Control-Allow-Origin %{AccessControlAllowOrigin}e env=AccessControlAllowOrigin
Header always set Access-Control-Allow-Methods "GET, POST, PUT, DELETE, OPTIONS" env=IsPreflight
Header always set Access-Control-Allow-Headers "Content-Type, Authorization, Accept, Accept-Language" env=IsPreflight
Header always set Access-Control-Max-Age "7200" env=IsPreflight
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_METHOD} OPTIONS
RewriteCond %{ENV:IsPreflight} 1
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ $1 [R=204,L]
```

The above code will inject the CORS headers in the response when its necessary.
With this code your server will allow CORS only from the the domains "url1.com" or "url2.com".

Here are some references

- https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Request/mode
- https://fetch.spec.whatwg.org/#simple-header

Comment: How to do the same for MEAN stack application?

Comment: @IpsitaRout, maybe this can help you: [How to enable CORS in MEAN STACK web app?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30216583/how-to-enable-cors-in-mean-stack-web-app)

Answer (score 3):

Thanks a lot! More than 6 hours to solve this.

In my nodejs server

```
npm install --save cors
```

at app.js I inserted the lines:

```
var cors = require('cors');
var app = express(); 
app.use(cors());
```

and in my react client:

```
var shape_for_db = JSON.stringify(layer.geometry);
const trechoRede = {
    method: "POST",
    mode: "cors",
    headers: {
        'Accept': 'application/json',
        'Content-Type': 'application/json'
    },
         body: shape_for_db
};
```

Comment: Thanks a lot dude! You saved my six hrs of life! :D :beer:

Answer (score 1):

The `mode:"no-cors"` options appears to be the issue. Remove that option and the `Content-Type` should be set to `"application/json"`