# Setting Content-Type in fetch request not working

Tags: javascript, json, reactjs, fetch-api

I am doing a remote fetch request to a server. The payload is in JSON format, so I want to change the `Content-Type` header to `application/json`. I have used the following code to do this:

```
let email = document.getElementById("email").value
let password = document.getElementById("password").value

const body = {"email":email, "password":password}
const headers = new Headers({
    "Content-Type": "application/json",
    "Content-Length": JSON.stringify(body).length
})
const options = {
    method: "POST",
    mode: "no-cors",
    headers: headers,
    body: JSON.stringify(body)
}
console.log(options)
const response = await fetch('http://xx.xx.xx.xxx/login', options)
const json = await response.json()
console.log(json)
```

However, in the Chrome developer tools console, the `Content-Type` header of the request is still `text/plain;charset=UTF-8`. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Fetch: post json data, application/json change to text/plain](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39689386/fetch-post-json-data-application-json-change-to-text-plain)

Answer (score 55):

Overriding the Content-Type request header is not allowed for `no-cors` requests.

Change the mode to `cors`.

(You won't be able to read the response without doing that either).

Comment: Which is, of course, utterly useless if you have an endpoint which doesn't CORS.  :-(

Comment: @Quentin yes. Just means extra stuff required to work around the problem.  eg, proxy the endpoint, modifying headers.  Or change the endpoint so that it does CORS.  I elected to proxy the endpoint rather than touch that old legacy code.  :-)

Comment: [Here is the relevant section of the documentation for fetch](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API/Using_Fetch#Supplying_request_options), that states that when using `no-cors` mode, you cannot set a value of `application/json` for the `Content-Type` header.