# Python Bottle is None from React JSON

Tags: javascript, python, bottle

I have this in React:

```
const payload = {
    x : x,
    y : y
}

fetch("http://localhost:8080/update_game", {
    method: "POST",
    body: JSON.stringify(payload)})
```

And this in Python:

```
@post('/update_game')
def update_game():
    req = request.json
    print(req);
```

I keep getting:

```
None
127.0.0.1 - - [24/Jan/2022 14:06:36] "POST /update_game HTTP/1.1" 200 0
```

I don't see what I would be doing different than all of the other examples I've been finding. `payload` successfully logs in the console. I have CORS set up and working correctly in Python. I also tried adding `contentType: application/JSON` to the react side. I don't see what I could be doing wrong here.

edit for clarity: I'm attempting to print out the json response in the terminal on the python side. I simply want to see that this response is going through.

I discovered this little bit, that does show something, but is not correct:

```
@post('/update_game')
def update_game():
    req = request.forms
    print(dir(req))
    print(dict(req))
    print(req)
```

the ouput:

```
{'{"x":"0","y":"6"}': ''}
```

And I also have this:

```
def update_game():
   req = request.headers['Content-Type']
   # print(dir(req))
   # print(dict(req))
   print(req)
```

output:

```
text/plain;charset=UTF-8
```

I'm pretty sure that should be `application/JSON`

Answer (score 0):

Starting from scratch...

```
$ python3 -m venv venv
$ source venv/bin/activate
$ python -m pip install -U bottle
```

Create `app.py`

```
from bottle import post, request, run

@post('/echo')
def echo():
    data = request.json
    print(type(data))
    return data  # example to return the input

run(host='localhost', port=8080, debug=True)
```

Run `python app.py`

From a new terminal, I pass the Content-Type along with a payload to return

```sh
$ curl -H 'Content-Type: application/json' -d'{"x": 2, "y":4}' http://localhost:8080/echo
{"x": 2, "y": 4}
```

In the server logs, I see

```
<class 'dict'>
127.0.0.1 - - [24/Jan/2022 17:13:38] "POST /echo HTTP/1.1" 200 16
```

See this post for properly sending JSON from Javascript without it being `text/plain` - [Setting Content-Type in fetch request not working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45655216/setting-content-type-in-fetch-request-not-working)

Answer (score 0):

I found one solution. Hopefully this one helps whoever is having the same issues.

```
import json
import io


@post('/update_game')
def update_game():
    encoding = "UTF-8"
    req = json.load(io.TextIOWrapper(request.body, encoding=encoding))
    print(req)
```