# POST Request Body is empty

Tags: mysql, node.js, reactjs

**Task**

- Parse a CSV file
- Send the data to an API enpoint
- Save data to MySql database

**Problem**

The request `body` is showing up empty when I send data via `fetch`. However, I can send and see the `body` data if I use Postman.

I've added a `console.log(req.body)` and it's printing out `{}` to the console.

**Parse and Send Data to Endpoint**

```
  const changeHandler = (event) => {
    Papa.parse(event.target.files[0], {
      header: true,
      skipEmptyLines: true,
      complete: function (results) {
        results.data.forEach(entry => {
          // Create the data object.
          let data = {};
          let keys = ['Date', 'Description', 'Debit Amount'];
          for (let key in entry) {
            if (keys.includes(key)) {
              data[key.toLowerCase().replaceAll(' ', '_')] = entry[key];
            }
          }
          // Send data to server
          fetch('http://localhost:3001/api/create_transactions', {
            method: 'POST',
            mode: 'no-cors',
            headers: { 'Content-Type': 'application/json' },
            body: JSON.stringify(data),
          }).then(function (response) {
            console.log(response);
          })
        });
      },
    });

    // Reset file input
    event.target.value = null;
  };
```

**Save Data to MySql**

```
app.use(express.json());

const crypto = require('crypto');

app.post("/api/create_transactions", (req, res) => {
  console.log(req.body);
  /*
  let hash = crypto.createHash('md5').update(req.body['date'] + req.body['description'] + req.body['debit_amount']).digest('hex');

  let data = [
    hash,
    req.body['date'],
    req.body['description'],
    req.body['debit_amount'],
  ];

  db.query('insert into transactions (`hash`, `date`, `description`, `debit_amount`) values (?, ?, ?, ?)', data, (err, result, fields) => {
    if (err) {
      console.log(err);
    } else {
      console.log(result);
      res.send(JSON.stringify({"status": 200, "error": null, "response": result}))
    }
  });
  */
});

app.listen(PORT, () => {
  console.log(`Server listening on ${PORT}`);
});
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Trying to use fetch and pass in mode: no-cors](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43262121/trying-to-use-fetch-and-pass-in-mode-no-cors). And this? [How to enable cors nodejs with express?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/43150051/283366)

Comment: it's not seems to be CORs issue at all @Phill

Comment: can you console log the req.headers?

Comment: @MMaavia I was able to log the req.headers. I noticed something that shouldn't be. The `content-type` is still set to `text/plain`. I tried setting my fetch headers to `new Headers({'Content-Type': 'application/json'})` and I'm still getting 'text/plain' in the request headers.

Comment: According to this post https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39689386/fetch-post-json-data-application-json-change-to-text-plain you can not change the `Content-Type` to `application/json` if you are using `no-cors`. So I will have to enable `cors` if I want to use `fetch`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to this post [Fetch: post json data, application/json change to text/plain](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39689386/fetch-post-json-data-application-json-change-to-text-plain) you can not change the `Content-Type` to `application/json` if you are using `no-cors`. So I will have to enable `cors` if I want to use `fetch`.

Using this tutorial https://www.section.io/engineering-education/how-to-use-cors-in-nodejs-with-express/ I was able to enable cors on my nodejs server and receive the proper headers.

Answer (score -1):

Try to use express's bodyParser `app.use(express.bodyParser());`