# JavaScript fetch() unable to set Content-Type header to "application/json"

Tags: javascript, json, http-headers, fetch-api

Currently attempting to `fetch` some JSON to an API. I am testing my `fetch` requests using [requestcatcher.com](https://requestcatcher.com). Here is an example, which highlights the problem I am having:

```js
fetch("https://example.requestcatcher.com",
{
    method: "POST",
    mode: "no-cors",
    headers: new Headers({ "Accept":"application/json", "Content-Type":"application/json" }),
    body: "{}"
});
```

Upon sending this request, I expected the request catcher API to receive the header `Content-Type: application/json`. However, this is not happening - the Content-Type keeps getting reset to `text/plain;charset=UTF-8`. This happens whether I pass in a `Headers` object or simply an `Object`. The `Content-Type` is also the only header to be modified in this way - the `Accept` header doesn't suffer this issue.

Interestingly, this substitution doesn't happen if I pass in `Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded`: that header, unlike `application/json`, is received unaltered by the request catcher. It seems to have an unique problem with `application/json`. I've seen no successful explanation online regarding why this would happen - if anyone is able to shed some light on this I would be much grateful.

Comment: Sometimes depending on the `body` value, the `Content-type` could be ignored. if you are sending a `formData` or a _formData-like_ it can ignore the fact that you are sending a JSON and it's pretty helpful, meaning that you don't have to bother yourself and specify the `Content-type`, let the server automatically detect the type.

Comment: the issue is [mode:no-cors](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Request/mode#no-cors) - you are limited to what headers you can set, and what `content-type` can be set to - i.e., anything that would trigger a CORS pre-flight is NOT allowed when mode is no-cors

Comment: [This also would be helpful](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39689386/fetch-post-json-data-application-json-change-to-text-plain)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This issue arises because of the `"no-cors"` mode you're using in your `fetch()` options. When making a `fetch()` request with the `no-cors` mode, you cannot set the `Content-Type header` to `'application/json'`, as this mode allows very limited headers and the `Content-Type header` for this mode is locked to a few safe ones, like `'text/plain'`.

Here's your remediated code:

```
fetch("https://example.requestcatcher.com",
{
    method: "POST",
    mode: "cors", // <-- Change this
    headers: {
        "Accept":"application/json", 
        "Content-Type":"application/json"
    },
    body: "{}"
});
```

Comment: `as the server at the endpoint should support CORS` - why SHOULD it? hint: it doesn't