# Google map response return No 'Access-control-allow-origin' error in MEAN stack app

Tags: javascript, angularjs, google-maps, mean-stack

I'm trying to get a list of nearby Places like restaurants etc from Google map but I'm getting this error. the request is going through angularjs not from express or node

XMLHttpRequest cannot load https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/nearbysearch/json?location=28.44…09&type=restaurant&key="keyhere"&radius=5000. No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'http://localhost:3000' is therefore not allowed access

Map Service

```
angular.module('core').factory('MapService', ['$resource',
    function($resource) {

        // console.log($resource);
        return $resource('', {}, {
            restaurants: { method: 'GET', url: 'https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/nearbysearch/json?location=:latitude,:longitude&type=restaurant&key=AIzaSyDx3BunF8A6xkppnzESbrljsCnWFe6LJWU&radius=5000', params: { latitude: '@_latitude', longitude: '@_longitude' } },
            banks: { method: 'GET', url: 'https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/nearbysearch/json?location=:latitude,:longitude&type=bank&key=AIzaSyDx3BunF8A6xkppnzESbrljsCnWFe6LJWU&radius=5000', params: { latitude: '@_latitude', longitude: '@_longitude' } },
            atms: { method: 'GET', url: 'https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/nearbysearch/json?location=:latitude,:longitude&type=atm&key=&radius=5000', params: { latitude: '@_latitude', longitude: '@_longitude' } },
            bus_stations: { method: 'GET', url: 'https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/nearbysearch/json?location=:latitude,:longitude&type=bus_station&key=&radius=5000', params: { latitude: '@_latitude', longitude: '@_longitude' } },
            train_stations: { method: 'GET', url: 'https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/nearbysearch/json?location=:latitude,:longitude&type=train_station&key=&radius=5000', params: { latitude: '@_latitude', longitude: '@_longitude' } },
            bars: { method: 'GET', url: 'https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/nearbysearch/json?location=:latitude,:longitude&type=bar&key=&radius=5000', params: { latitude: '@_latitude', longitude: '@_longitude' } },
            hospitals: { method: 'GET', url: 'https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/nearbysearch/json?location=:latitude,:longitude&type=hospital&key=&radius=5000', params: { latitude: '@_latitude', longitude: '@_longitude' } },
            gyms: { method: 'GET', url: 'https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/nearbysearch/json?location=:latitude,:longitude&type=gym&key=&radius=5000', params: { latitude: '@_latitude', longitude: '@_longitude' } },
            ditance_time: { method: 'GET', url: 'https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/distancematrix/json?units=metric&origins=:o_latitude,:o_longitude&destinations=:d_latitude,:d_longitude&key=', params: { o_latitude: '@_o_latitude', o_longitude: '@_o_longitude', d_latitude: '@_d_latitude', d_longitude: '@_d_longitude' } },


        });
    }
]);
```

If I enable the Allow-Access-Control-Origin it works and I have tried including the headers in $resource it still doesn't work

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to enable CORS in MEAN STACK web app?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30216583/how-to-enable-cors-in-mean-stack-web-app)

Comment: @MuhammadSaqlain but I'm calling google map service from Angularjs what does that have to do with Node.js??

Comment: You need to enable CORS.

Comment: @MuhammadSaqlain Can you please tell me the steps to do so