# valid json format gives error “<“ while parsing also view engine error 500 using mean stack angular 2+

Tags: html, json, angular, mean-stack

Mean server with angular 2+.
I have a dataservice.js that requests a get to the server, to receive a json response from the http://localhost:3000/server/routes/api/test.js
This gives me an error 500 view engine not selected,
My understanding is angular doesn’t require a view engine? As the angular/ browser takes care of that.

Somehow the routing doesn’t seem to work when I do a getter to the api.

The angular routes work with the html components, but via the dataservice a get request to the mongodb doesn’t work either. The get/test most often returns error 500 no view engine selected as well.

If it does return something, it returns an error message “<“ not in jsn format.

How do I make sure that the routing works for my get and post messages and they are returned back in json format and not in HTML.
And how do I figure out that it uses the correct routing? I somehow doubt that the rouitng for the get/ post messages seem to use express rather then the angular modules

I am quite new to stack overflow/ Mean server so if you require more info please let me know.

FYI
I have been able to get a json file from the server (not the database) via a get. This worked. So why is it that a get to the database doesn’t seem to work and the same question about why I can’t seem to get a json response from the http://localhost:3000/server/routes/test/api.js in the api.

I spent a full 2 days troubleshooting to no result.

```
in my api.js

router.get ('/test', function (req, res, next) {
res.json({'testMessage': 'everything is going ', 'someNumber': 457});
    });
```

In the server.js

```
   <!-- end snippet -->
  <!-- begin snippet: js hide: false console: true babel: false -->
  <!-- language: lang-js -->
  var express = require('express');
  var path = require('path');
  var favicon = require('serve-favicon');
  var logger = require('morgan');
  var bodyParser = require('body-parser');
  var morgan = require ('morgan');
  var mongoose = require('mongoose');
  var flash = require('connect-flash');
  var chat = require('./server/routes/chat');
  var app = express();

  var passport = require ('passport');
var cookieParser = require ('cookie-parser');
var session = require ('express-session');
var config = require ('./config/database');
var engines = require('consolidate');
var mongoose = require('mongoose');
var router = express.Router(); 
// this is where I set up the routing for the api  
// in the root of the project I created server directory and 
// within it a routes directory that holds the api.js
var api = require('./server/routes/api');


mongoose.Promise = require ('q').Promise;

require('./config/passport')(passport);
app.use(logger('dev'));

app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({'extended':'true'}));
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'dist')));
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'public')));
app.use(cookieParser());
app.use(morgan('dev'));
app.use(session({
 secret: 'secret123',
 resave: true,
saveUnitialized: true
}));
app.use(passport.initialize());
app.use(passport.session());
app.use(flash());
//this is where I set up the routing is something  wrong here?

app.get('*', (req, res) => {
 res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname, 'dist/index.html'));
});
app.use('api', api);
```

Comment: Have you tried to use the API directly from the browser? Since it's a GET call, you can just post the URL in the search address and inspect the result. It seems that the issue is _not_ in your Angular code, but in your API implementation, but you should verify that.

Comment: I checked it in the browser, which usually returns me the 500 error but never any results from the josn file, I do see an html output when I check the debugger. Will usng cors help me? Just read this post: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30216583/how-to-enable-cors-in-mean-stack-web-app. could not having cors or specifically adding .json to the request solve my issue.

Comment: That tells us the issue is on the server side. Use debugger, or look into logs to get an idea.

Answer (score 0):

thx everyone, I moved

```
app.get('*', (req, res) => {
res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname, 'dist/index.html'));
});
```

below

```
app.use('api', api);
```

and changed it to:

```
app.use('/api', api);
```

Problem solved, if app.get('*') is read first it will send all requests to index.html instead. So make sure any other routings go above it.